# Response compression in .net core web api

Tags: c#, .net-core, compression, asp.net-core-webapi

We are trying to implement response compression using below package in .net core web api for better performance.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression -Version 2.2.0
```

However, we have realized that this package is deprecated and no longer maintained.

So, what is the alternate package for the same?

Comment: ResponseCompression is available in .net 7.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @DavidG We are using .net 6.0

Comment: It is also included in Asp.Net Core 6.0 (and might have been since 3.x, not sure). No need for an extra nuget package.